# ng-click function isn't called

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

```
<body ng-app="groupChatApp" ng-controller="groupChatController">
    <div id="error-container">{{errorValue}}</div>
    <div ng-model="changeForm" id="changeForm">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="ENTER YOU NAME!" ng-model="name">
        <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="setUsername()">Let me chat!</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('groupChatApp', []);
    app.controller('groupChatController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.errorValue = "";
        $scope.messageDisplay = "";
        var socket = io();
        $scope.setUsername = function () {
            socket.emit('setUsername', $scope.name);
        }
        $scope.sendMessage = function () {
            var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
            if (msg) {
                socket.emit('msg', {message: msg, user: user});
            }
        }
        var user;
        socket.on('userExists', function (data) {
            $scope.errorValue = data;
        });
        socket.on('userSet', function (data) {
            user = data.username;
            document.getElementById('changeForm').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="message"><button type="button" ng-click="sendMessage()">Send</button>'
                    + '<div id="message-container"></div>';
            ;
        });
        socket.on('newmsg', function (data) {
            if (user) {
                document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += '<div><b>' + data.user + '</b>: ' + data.message + '</div>'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying is a socket.io group chat application - node js.
Here, ng-click isn't functioning on clicking the button. I feel like it isn't entering the function. When I use onclick and the function name it works. But ng-click doesn't. I could't spot it out. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

users = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');
    socket.on('setUsername', function (data) {

        if (users.indexOf(data) > -1) {
            socket.emit('userExists', data + ' username is taken! Try some other username.');
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            users.push(data);
            socket.emit('userSet', {username: data});
        }
    });

    socket.on('msg', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('newmsg', data);
        console.log('hi');
    })
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

This is my script file in node js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ng-click isn't functioning on clicking the button. I feel like it
>   isn't entering the function.

Which function is not called ?

I see that you are mixing pure Javascript with AngularJS which is not the best idea. When you are trying to work with AngularJS try to stick with it, try to do it the "Angular" way.

I see only one function that could not be called - `sendMessage()` and I assume that you get to the point of successful entering the chat room. Now I will explain you why your function is not called:

You are dynamically updating the HTML - angular doesn't know nothing about your new HTML. In order to let angular know what this new HTML should do, you need to **compile** this HTML with desired scope. So for example you can change your code like this:

```
// use angular to get this element and not the getElementById function
var container = angular.element('#changeForm');

// update HTML using html() method
container.html(
        '<input type="text" id="message">' +
        '<button type="button" ng-click="sendMessage()">Send</button>' +
        '<div id="message-container"></div>'
);

// now in order your new HTML to work you need to compile it
$compile(container)($scope);
```

We need to inject the **[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)** service if we want the above code to work:

```
app.controller('groupChatController', function ($scope, $compile) { ...
```

Something else:

```
var socket = io();

// I think above code should be 
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

### CONCLUSION

This code will work, but I **strongly discourage** you to do it this way.

What I will do:

- Use **ng-view** + **ng-route** to separate the chat room login view with the chat room view - see [**this**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm) for example how to use ng-view and ng-route
- Use different controller for the chat room login and actual chat room
- update my views with the magical binding that AngularJS provides us and **NOT** update view via **VanillaJS**(getElementById, querySelector, etc ...)

So when using AngularJS this:

```
document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += '<div><b>' + data.user + '</b>: ' + data.message + '</div>';
```

**is a bad practice** and you should change it to something like that:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="message-container">
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <span>{{message.user}}:</span>
        <span>{{message.message}}</span>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.messages = [];
socket.on('newmsg', function (data) {
    if (user) {
        $scope.messages.push(data);
    }
});
```

Just try to do it more Angular style when using AngularJS :)